# Powershell : unable to open a serial port with an event handler (button)

Tags: powershell, serial-port, eventhandler

I would like to open a serial port with powershell by a click on a button inside an User Interface.

However when i click on this button, the port is not created, my code is below :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = ‘500,500’
$Form.Text = 'My UI'

$TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(250,60)
$TextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)

$Bouton5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Bouton5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(250,110)
$Bouton5.Width = 100
$Bouton5.Height = 40
$Bouton5.Text = 'Open Port COM'
$Form.controls.Add($Bouton5)
$Bouton5.Add_Click({ $PortName = $TextBox.Text
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $PortName,9600,None,8,one 
$port.open() }) 

$Bouton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Bouton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,250)
$Bouton.Width = 100
$Bouton.Height = 40
$Bouton.Text = 'Programmation (ROM APP)'
$Form.controls.Add($Bouton)
$Bouton.Add_Click($port.WriteLine("p")})
```

Basically, I want  to take COM# from the TextBox, user will fill the TextBox, and then clicking on the button will create then open the port. However, only this  happens when i'm writing something after my `.Open()` :

```
+ $port.WriteLine("p")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? Any idea ? please

Comment: "nothing happens with my port." you're not really... doing anything? What happens if you try to write to it after `.Open()`?

Comment: Sry, forgot to show the "error mesage"... I edited the main post

Comment: When you open the port, what should happen next? IIRC, you have to call `$port.ReadLine()` to handle input from a serial port, right?

Comment: The $port variable seems to be only present within your event handling code. What happens if you define $port outside of that code? ($port = $null)?

Comment: yes if I open the port outside the event handling code it will open, it seems i can't open a open within an event handling like a button 
After this code i have an other code which does $port.ReadLine() and $port.WriteLine('u')

Comment: I can't open a port within an event... *
Furthermore, when i said "i have an other code", it means i call my port later

Comment: Okay, it seems, the port which is define inside the event handling can't be use outside this event code. Do you have any idea how to define a serialport inside an event and can be use in every other event? I edited the main post where i would like to use the $port in "Bouton" even if i define it in "Bouton5".

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue, right know i create the `$port` inside each button ... i would like to define it for every other event